# Publish Blazor WebAssembly With VS2022 Ver 17.2.5 Error

Tags: blazor, publish, blazor-webassembly

Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.2.5 released with support of dot NET Ver 6.0.301.

In this version, if you publish the blazor webassembly project, you got error:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(614,5):
> Error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" exited with code 1.

This error is a bug on dot NET 6.0.301 and you have to downgrade the system or change project to use dot NET version to 6.0.300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, Open Microsoft dot NET download page:

   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.300-windows-x64-installer
2. Download and Install the earlier version (6.0.300).
3. Add *[global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)* file to solution in file explorer. (close to *X.sln* file)
4. Well, at the end, you have to paste this content to *global.json* file:

> ```
> {
>   "sdk": {
>     "version": "6.0.300"
>   }
> }
> ```

5. Publish the project again.

Comment: This worked for me, as getting desperate. Make sure you add the global.json file to the root directory of the solution.